# 404 status on bootstrap.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I got this error from my bootstrap.js. what is the error and how can i fix this?

```
 GET http://localhost/hr/public/js/booststrap.js index:12
 status 404
```

My header code is,

```
<!--DOCTYPE html-->

<html lang="en">

<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>public/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>public/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">

        <script src="<?php echo base_url()?>public/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url()?>public/js/booststrap.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<header>
Header
</header>
```

i am using code igniter on xampp.

Comment: I think it should be `<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>hr/public/js/booststrap.js"></script>`

Comment: What is the value of `base_url()`??

Comment: Make sure you have set your base_url to `http://localhost/hr/` and also make sure your css and java script out side of application folder.

Comment: Are you sure that shouldn't be `bootstrap.js`?

Comment: my config is 

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/hr/';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change the script tags to this:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>public/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>public/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

And, as suggested by @wolfgang1983 make sure to edit the `base_url` in the config file to `http://localhost/hr/`

Comment: it is already set to 

$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/hr/';

Comment: Are you trying to use a cdn??

Comment: If it is base_url is set, I think there is a path error in the script tag, it should be `bootstrap.js` not `booststrap.js`

Comment: oh. so its bootstrap. haha! i thought its booststrap! thanks!